# How do I make my website secure in Google Chrome?

Tags: linux, apache, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I am working on a web development project and I was testing it primarily on Firefox. However, when I tried it on Google Chrome, it would not load completely and Chrome would warn me that the site had "insecure content". After searching for answers, I was advised to make my website use "https" rather than "http". I do not know much about SSL or anything like it, but I followed a set of instructions for setting up Apache to work with SSL. The instructions are here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04

I followed them. The good news is, my website is accessable by https. The bad news is, unless https is typed, the website is inaccessible. On top of that, both Chrome and Firefox present messages saying "this certificate is not trusted", which is ironic, since I only did any of this to secure the site in the first place.

Can anyone show me where I went wrong or give a more complete explanation of what's going on? I am working on Ubuntu 12.10 with Apache 2 and PHP5.

Comment: You need to (a) get a certificate from a trusted authority; this will make the "not trusted" error go away and (b) you need to setup an automatic redirect from http to https. This question is off-topic for StackOverflow though.

Comment: You need to learn how HTTPS works.  What was the error you originally got in Chrome?  Unless you're dealing with sensitive data (eg, a login form), you don't need HTTPS at all.

Comment: I am requesting login information. In Chrome, a shield would appear at the end of the url bar that says that the site had insecure content.

Comment: @Gregory-Turtle: That means that you're already on HTTPS, but that some resources aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search online to get the best SSL vendor and use that we use symantec at work http://www.symantec.com/theme.jsp?themeid=compare-ssl-certificates

use the below javascript to redirect http to https.

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

"this certificate is not trusted" message is due to the fact that you are using a self-generated certificate.  SSL uses a trusted third party (certificate authority) to ensure secure communication.  You will need to purchase a certificate from one of these for your production environment.  Simple google SSL certificate and you will get a whole bunch of options.